# Fail to search a wikidata item through SPARQL

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I tried to search and get the ID of a item with a certain label: `Teodor Bogdanov`. I can search this name successfully through [wikidata website](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q22277104). However, I failed to do so by searching through SPARQL. The code is [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20WHERE%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Teodor%20Bogdanov%22.%0A%7D).

I also copied it here:

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE{  
  ?item ?label "Teodor Bogdanov".
}
```

The same thing happens for `Félix Anaut`

Could anyone help me fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://w.wiki/5Ate

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE{  
  ?item ?label "Teodor Bogdanov"@en .
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a DESCRIBE Query:
with a `wd` Prefix: `wd:Teodor Bogdanov<wait for autocompleter substitution>` to get Q.... identifier

```
DESCRIBE wd:Q22277104  # Teodor Bogdanov, Volleyball player
```

Result:

```
wd:Q22277104    wdt:P569            29 January 1986 
wd:Q22277104    schema:dateModified 11 October 2022 
wd:Q22277104    schema:version      1747954437  
wd:Q22277104    wdt:P21             wd:Q6581097
and many more rows
```

Simliar SPARQL Query for Félix Anaut, Spanish Painter

```
DESCRIBE wd:Q5442128  # Félix Anaut, Spanish Painter
```

(Results not shown here)